# Route everything in URL after domain to index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this .htaccess file but it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [R,L]
```

What I see in Apache error log is [Error: Over 10 times of redirecting internally].
I added the flag 'L' in RewriteRule but it doesn't stop after the first time matching the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running v2.2.16+ then use FallbackResource, see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

The alternative is to use mod_rewrite and the code should be as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```